# Win8 ASP.net HttpRouteUrl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, winapi

I am pretty new to Win8 and ASP.net development, I apologize for any lack of clarity or specification as I am a 3D graphics programmer by trade and taking on developing an ASP.net back end system. The goal is communicate with a target Win8 app to consume data that is input via the ASP.net website by a user(admin).

I am hitting multiple hurdles and dead ends with it being new Win8 technologies and few sound reference materials.

Within HomeController.cs I am attempting to call:

```
 public ActionResult Admin()
    {

        string apiUri = Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "testModel", });
        ViewBag.ApiUrl = new Uri(Request.Url, apiUri).AbsoluteUri.ToString();

        return View();
    }
```

So that I can enable routing to my Admin controller. However I get the following output in the browser:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JCq4.png

I am using an example project I downloaded from the internet as a skeleton framework as it contains the WebApiConfig.cs file, whereas generating a new VS2012 ASP.NET MVC Web Application project does not contain this file and I believe I need it as it is the point I am able to specify that I want to serialize as JSON and remove XML formatting.

I have cleaned out .DLL files in bin and cleaned the obj folder in case it was referencing an object that no longer exists.

There are several other projects that I have created, one that uses the VS2012 MVC Web app project generated from the wizard, it implements:

```
 Url.RouteUrl
```

instead of

```
 Url.HttpRouteUrl
```

But I am sure this does not achieve the same effect, as I want to communicate http over the internet from a server to the target app. If I try to use latter, it errors:

```
   'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'HttpRouteUrl' and no extension method 'HttpRouteUrl' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

As reference, this is the article I am using to assist this portion of the project:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/using-web-api-with-entity-framework,-part-4

I appreciate the help(this is very different from OpenGl and DirectX)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a standard MVC controller action, not an ApiController action, the Url property inside this controller is just the standard [UrlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

You could use the following:

```
public ActionResult Admin()
{
    string apiUri = Url.RouteUrl(
        "DefaultApi", 
        new { httproute = "", controller = "Values" }, 
        Request.Url.Scheme
    );
    ViewBag.ApiUrl = apiUri;
    return View();
}
```

Notice the `httproute = ""` that is used in the routeValues parameter as well as how specifying the protocol argument generates an absolute url so that you don't need to tweak with by creating new `Uri` objects and stuff..

Comment: Thanks for the response Darin, the apiUri is now storing "http://localhost:portnum/api/testModel" as opposed to null.